# How to use multiple thread to process image with openCV?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

I want to use the multi thread to process each frame captured in the video,So first of all, I tried a simple test:show the same video in the two thread,but the question is that the sub-thread can't show the video. It just can show the main thread's video.Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Here is my code:

```
HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, false, "IMG");  
int main()
{
  videoMultiThread();
  return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI TL_FRAME(LPVOID lpParamter)
{
  WaitForSingleObject(hMutex,INFINITE);
  IplImage* frame=(IplImage*)lpParamter;
  cvShowImage("TL",frame);
  cvWaitKey(5);
  cout<<"Thread captured"<<endl;
  ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
  return 0;
}

void videoMultiThread()
{
    CvCapture * cap=cvCreateFileCapture("VIDEO.avi");
    IplImage * frame;
    while(1)
   {
    WaitForSingleObject(hMutex,INFINITE);
    frame=cvQueryFrame(cap);
    if(!frame)break;
    cvShowImage( "frame",frame); 
    cout<<"main thread captured"<<endl;
    //MultiThread
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,TL_FRAME,frame,0,NULL);
    CloseHandle(hThread);

    char c=waitKey(5);
    if (c==27)break;
    ReleaseMutex(hMutex); 
   }
   cvReleaseCapture(&cap);
   cvDestroyAllWindows();
}
```

Comment: can you try to call `cv::namedWindow("TL")` in the main thead before thread creation? If that doesnt work try `cv::namedWindow("TL")` in the threaded function. Typically you should use cv::namedWindow once before cv::imshow, but normally if you are lazy, cv::imshow can implicitly create that window, BUT: in multiple threads this often doesnt work.

Comment: btw, did you lock the mutex anywhere?!?

Comment: and I dont know how WaitForSingleObject works, you should std::cout at some points before and after thread entry to verify that cv::imshow / cv::waitKey is reached!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried add the cvNamedWindow("TL") in the main thread before the TL_FRAME thread, it will make the program block. When I add the cvNameWindow("TL") in the  TL_FRAME thread, only the main thread can show the video. I didn't lock the mutex in other place., and I'm sure the function imshow and waitkey have been reached!@Micka

Comment: can you move to c++ version of openCV? Probably you can only use GUI stuff in the main thread... But there is another thing, can you try `cvStartWindowThread` at the very beginning of your main thread?

Comment: I add cvNamedWindow("TL")  both in the main thread and TL_FRAME thread and it worked! But and don't know why....Any more, thanks a lot for your help!@Micka

Comment: because without that you are just not allowed to call imshow from different threads than the main thread. That's a limitation of opencv. But remember that highGui isn't made for production code anyways. it's made for fast testing of your computer vision methods without coding some "real" gui.